# Real time notification webapp with nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I want to build a recipe maker webapp for practicing.

This webapp will contain 2 web pages: index and recipes.

On ,,index" the clients can make some recipes.

On the ,,recipes" page the user can see a table of recipes made by her/him and by other users (the last 10 or so).

The recipes will be stored in a database.

This sounds easy until now, but if a user creates a recipe and clicks on the ,,Add" button, I want to update the recipes table in the recipe page without refreshing, so it will contain the new recipe (like real-time notification).

Can I use node.js, express.js and socket.io to make this kind of behavior? If so, what functions, features should I look up? Recently I started learning these technologies but I can't see how can I pass data between pages and how to invoke functions if the data has arrived (maybe routing?).

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Yes, you can implement the idea using the stated technologies. Further you may want to look at their `getting started` and then come back to us if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely you can use these technologies or others. Its all about, with what you are comfortable with.

Secondly, Look at their getting started. `Socket.io` has few github repo to get started. It is pretty easy. I did it in around 10mins with 0% experience in socket.

Socket.io has node.js documentation too. HTML and JS are just complementing resources for look and feel.

Ref: https://github.com/shah-smit/socket.io-getting-started

Lastly, you want to take a look at JQuery for animation.